# Occurrences by Year-Month in Presto DB

Tags: sql, presto

I have a table in Presto with this schema:

```
created_at  Record
timestamp   String
```

`created_at` has records from 2020 to 2022.

What's the best way to get the total number of record by month, like this output:

```
Date        N_Records
2020-01       1000
2020-02       1500
----
2022-03       3000
```

**What I did so far:**

```
select date_format(created_at, '%b') month, count(*) count
from table
group by date_format(created_at, '%b')
order by 1 asc
```

**Problems with my code**:

I don't have the respective `year` and the results are not sorted by asc month.

Can someone help with to improve my query?

Answer (score 0):

You can use format including 4-digit year and 2-digit month:

```sql
select date_format(created_at, '%Y-%m') Date, count(*) N_Records
from table
group by 1
order by 1 asc
```